# how to validate bing maps api key?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, bing-api, bing-maps

I am using the leaflet bing maps plugin.
How can I validate the bing maps api key before it's used by leaflet?

If I allow an invalid key to be used like this:

```
var bing_key = "funTimeWithBingMaps"
baseMapUrl = new L.BingLayer(bing_key)
```

Then bing maps reports:

"Leaflet Bing Plugin Error - Got metadata: Access was denied. You may have entered your credentials incorrectly, or you might not have access to the requested resource or operation."

And then `map.removeLayer(baseMapUrl);` fails to remove the layer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own key by using this website: http://www.bingmapsportal.com/

Once you have logged in with a Microsoft account (aka Live ID), you will be able to generate several keys based on your usage. For more information about the type of key, check the MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428642.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's really ugly but here's a 'solution'.

```
var map, osm, bing, count_down = 50;

    function first_part()
    {
    map = new L.Map('map', {center: new L.LatLng(67.6755, 33.936), zoom: 10 });
    osm = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');

    bing = new L.BingLayer("MyBingApiKeyGoesHere");
    setTimeout(function () { second_part(bing); }, 100);
    }

    function second_part(binz)
    {
        if (typeof(binz.meta.statusCode) == 'undefined') {
            count_down--;
            if (count_down == 0) {
                alert("abandon operation");
                return;
            }
            setTimeout(function () { second_part(binz); }, 100);
            return;
            }
        if (binz.meta.statusCode == 200) {
            alert("OK");
            map.addLayer(bing);
            map.addControl(new L.Control.Layers({'OSM':osm, "Bing":bing}, {}));
            }
        else {
            alert("WRONG: count_down: "+count_down+"  statusCode: "+binz.meta.statusCode);
            }
    }

    first_part();
```